# In R, how do I change the number and spacing of the tick marks on the x-axis of my plot when the values are dates?

Tags: r, plot, x-axis

I have to create a plot of prices over time, and the time is given in dates down to the month. The problem I'm having so far is that there are just four tick marks, for 2005, 2010, 2015, and 2020, and they're spaced really far apart. It looks ugly and it's harder to interpret. I want marks for 2005, 2008, 2011, 2014, 2017, and 2020 (but it still has to accommodate the dates beginning at January 2005 and ending at October 2020). All the solutions I've seen online for changing the tick marks this way seem to require that the values be numbers, not dates. Here's the relevant code I've got so far:

```
Date <- parse_datetime(YearAndMonth, "%Y %b")

plot(Date,England, type="l", col="red", ylim=c(90000,300000), ylab="Price (£)")
```

Thank you.

Comment: Try use ggplot with scale_x_date(date_breaks = "3 year") so that you get 2005, 2008, 2011, 2014, 2017, 2020.

Comment: Please, provide a minimal reproducible example. https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/